# USB with Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS installed bootable in macbook pro 2014 and not macbook pro 2019

Tags: boot, usb, mac, macbook-pro

The difference with other questions of the sort is that I have the OS installed in this USB, it's not an installation media. I can boot into this USB perfectly with my macbook pro 2014, yet in my 2019's the usb is not even recognized. I already removed the T2's startup disk security using recovery mode. Does anyone have any ideas of how to boot into the USB?

Comment: Might Ubuntu be installed to BIOS boot?

Comment: No, it's a UEFI boot, I checked that by finding the folder /sys/firmware/efi